# node js: child_process.exec not actually waiting

Tags: node.js, async-await

Please consider this piece of code:

```
var cmd = `cd "${dir}" && curl -L "${url}" | tar -xJvf - | zip -qr archive.zip -@`;
await exec(cmd);
res.sendFile(path.join(dir, "archive.zip"));
```

It downloads a .tar.xz, untars it and rezip and finally send to user.

If I run it, it fails at `res.sendFile(...)` saying that the file does not exists. However, If I look into my file system, the zip is actually there.

So I tried to add a small delay before `res.sendFile(...)`, like this:

```
var cmd = `cd "${dir}" && curl -L "${url}" | tar -xJvf - | zip -qr archive.zip -@`;
await exec(cmd);

setTimeout(()=>{
    res.contentType(path.join(dir, "archive.zip"));
    res.sendFile(path.join(dir, "archive.zip"));
}, 1000);
```

...and it magically worked.

It seems that `exec(cmd)` doesn't actually waits for the command to be completed. Is it because it's piped?

Comment: Well most likely exec does not return a promise, but needs triggers a callback when finished. Please look at: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Comment: Ah yes! Shame on me! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well exec does not realy work like that.

The await keyword expects a Promise to wait for. Since exec will only return a child process object and requires to call a callback then ready, this wont work.

But there is a util in node to convert these regular node functions to promise functions called util.promisify. [nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

this is also shown in the documentation of exec (see https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback at the end of this paragraph)

```js
let util = require('util')
let exec = require('child_process').exec
let exec_prom = util.promisify(exec)

exec_prom('ip address').then(()=>{console.log('done')})


async function do(){
  await exec_prom('ip address');
  // do something after
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has [synchronous process creation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options):

```
child_process.execFileSync(file[, args][, options])
child_process.execSync(command[, options])
child_process.spawnSync(command[, args][, options])
```

`execSync` is the synchronous counterpart for the asynchronous `exec`:

> The child_process.execSync() method is generally identical to
> child_process.exec() with the exception that the method will not
> return until the child process has fully closed.

Simply use those functions for waiting for the result of the command.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

try {
    const result = execSync(cmd);
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```