# How to use node's child_process.exec() with promises

Tags: node.js, exec, child-process

I try to execute long processes sequentially with node.js (docker exec commands).

I do:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

const execWithPromise = async command => {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        const process = childProcess.exec(command);

        process.on('exit', err => resolve(err));
        process.on('close', err => resolve(err));
    });
};

const run = async () => {
    await execWithPromise('/usr/local/bin/docker exec -i -t cucumber node long-running-script.js');
    await execWithPromise('/usr/local/bin/docker exec -i -t cucumber node long-running-script.js');
};

run();
```

But the promise is resolved immediately with a result of 1. In both cases. The command runs on the commandline just fine.

Why is it returning immediately?

Comment: Another way to use exec with a promise is through util.promisify: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56095793/2604813

Comment: Use execSync instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850034/2101864

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`child_process.exec` expects a callback as the second or third argument.  It doesn't return a promise.  You have a few choices depending on your use case and version of node. The following work with node 16.x

Use a callback and return the resolve.

```
const execWithPromise = command =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    childProcess.exec(command, (err, stout, sterr) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(sterr)
      } else {
        resolve(stout)
      }
    })
  })
```

Use spawn instead (keeping most of your code)

```
const execWithPromise = command => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const process = childProcess.spawn(command);
      let data = '';
      let error = '';
      process.stdout.on('data', stdout => {
        data += stdout.toString();
      });
      process.stderr.on('data', stderr => {
        error += stderr.toString();
      });
      process.on('error', err => {
        reject(err);
      })
      process.on('close', code => {
        if (code !== 0) {
          reject(error)
        } else {
          resolve(data)
        }
        process.stdin.end();
      });
  });
```

Use execSync

```
const execWithPromise = command => childProcess.execSync(command).toString();
```

Comment: is it necessary for the callback to be an `async` function? Is not calling `reject` due to the inconsistent way command line execution can return to either stout or sterr depending on the program being executed? Thanks for these examples!

Comment: The function passed to a promise is not a callback. It's a function that is executed *synchronously* when the promise is created, and *exposes* the two `resolve` and `reject` callbacks. The promise would be pointless, as the `new Promise` call wouldn't return until the operation is complete. `execSync` will return successfully if the command returns a 0 exit code, otherwise throws the error. If the command being run writes to stderr and then exits with 0, then you would need to use the spawn method and figure out what to do based on the text (arguably, that would be a bug in the command).

Comment: @EricHaynes thanks for bringing this to my attention. I've updated for node 16 and fully tested each solution. I'm not sure if they ever were correct!

Answer (score 3):

### Here's an answer for current node.js:

#### TypeScript

For TypeScript, in `app.ts`:

```
import { exec as lameExec } from "child_process";
const exec = promisify(lameExec);
const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(`some command to run`);
```

You can then run this using esrun (`npm i @digitak/esrun`) which supports top level await:

`npx esrun app.ts`

#### JavaScript

In JS call the file `app.mjs` and run it with

`node app.mjs`

Comment: How would you get the stout or sterr of the child process?

Comment: `const {stdout, stderr, err} = await execute('')`

Comment: can somone help me with spwansync

Comment: Good answer, note you don't need async wrappers anymore, you can just use await at the top level. I've updated the answer accordingly.